# Class objects seem to reset

Tags: python, object, iteration

I am a C Programmer, but want to prototype some of my projects in python, so far its alright, but I'm stuck on a probably easy problem:
I have a Class which internals are not working, when I recreate the internals in the the main module everything is working so I assume something is wrong with my use of self or the iteration.

CBallSpawner:

```
 from CBullet import Bullet

 class BulletSpawner:

        def __init__(self, count, position, color, radius, speed):
            self.bull = []
            self.cnt = count
            self.speed = speed
            self.freeze = False
            self.acc = 0
            self.position = position

            self.createBullets(color, radius)

        def createBullets(self, color, radius):
            for i in range(1, self.cnt + 1):
                self.bull.append(Bullet(radius, 0, color, i*(360.0/self.cnt), self.speed, self.position))

        def speedUp(self, delta):
            self.acc += delta
            if self.acc > 1000 and not self.freeze:
                self.speed += 0.1
                for b in self.bull:
                    b.speed = self.speed
                self.acc = 0

        def tick(self, delta, w, h, window):
            self.speedUp(delta)
            for e in self.bull:
                e.tick(delta, w, h)

        def draw(self, window):
            for c in self.bull:
                window.draw(c.bullet_object)
```

The object's are created but are stuck in their initial position. When I debug the location of the objects in bull are not changing. If the delta is high enough the bullets seem to move randomly.

In the main I call

```
spawner = BulletSpawner(10, sf.Vector2(w/2, h/2), sf.Color.WHITE, 5, 0.16)
spawner.tick(delta, w, h, window)
spawner.draw(window)
```

The Bullet Class and the exact same Iteration are working fine in the main Module, but since I outsourced this in to the BulletSpawner Class the Bullets won't move properly anymore. Thanks in advice
E: The important parts of Bullet, which are working perfectly on its own

```
class Bullet:

    def __init__(self, radius, outline, color, phi, speed, position):
        self.phi = 0
        self.speed = speed
        self.bullet_object = sf.CircleShape()
        self.position = sf.Vector2()
        self.bounding_pos = sf.Vector2()
        self.motion = sf.Vector2()
        self.bounding = sf.Rectangle()

        self.bullet_object.outline_thickness = outline
        self.bullet_object.fill_color = color
        self.bullet_object.origin = (radius, radius)
        self.bullet_object.radius = radius

        self.bounding.size = sf.Vector2(radius*2,radius*2)
        self.bounding.position = self.position - (self.bounding.size/2)

        self.position = position
        self.phi = phi

        self.calulateMotion()

    def calulateMotion(self):
        self.motion.x = math.cos(self.phi * (math.pi / 180))
        self.motion.y = math.sin(self.phi * (math.pi / 180))

    def tick(self, delta, w, h):
        tmp = sf.Vector2(0, 0)
        tmp.x = self.position.x + (self.motion.x * (self.speed * delta))
        tmp.y = self.position.y + (self.motion.y * (self.speed * delta))

        if tmp.x < 0 or tmp.x > w:
            self.motion.x = -self.motion.x
            self.bullet_object.fill_color = sf.Color(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))

        if tmp.y < 0 or tmp.y > h:
            self.motion.y = -self.motion.y
            self.bullet_object.fill_color = sf.Color(random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255))

        self.position.x += self.motion.x * (self.speed * delta)
        self.position.y += self.motion.y * (self.speed * delta)

        self.bullet_object.position = self.position
        self.bounding.position = self.position - (self.bounding.size/2)
```

Edit: Funny Enough if I just create a spawner object with 1 Bullet so :

```
spawner = BulletSpawner(1, sf.Vector2(w/2, h/2), sf.Color.WHITE, 5, 0.16)
```

The Bullet is moving correctly

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand your problem since you don't get any example output, and you don't say what your values of delta, etc. are.  Nothing in the code you show changes the positions of any of the items in `bull`.  What does your `Bullet` class look like?

Comment: Have you tested the Bullet object by itself? It's doing the moving, but you don't include it's code here.

Comment: The Bullet Class on its one is working perfectly, The Iteration (outside a class) is also working perfectly so I have to assume that there is something wrong in this Class. As I said the outcome is that the Bullets seem to don't move = stuck in their initial position. If its for use I'll include the files, but I didn't want to spam the whole source. All values (delta / w / h ...) have good Data input.

Comment: Can you please try force float opeartions, i.e. wherever you have divisions like `w/2` change to `w/2.`, with the floating point, which may prevent some wrong results due to Python interpreting your numbers as integers.

Comment: is it right your `speedUp` method? It seems that the if check should be: `if self.acc < 1000 and not self.freeze:` ...

Comment: Right thanks and done, but sadly doesn't solve the problem. And yes acc is counting time, so I just speed up every 1 second, which also works fine when implemented outside the Spawner class by its own

Comment: Have you written any unit tests for your classes?

Comment: Okay, wow, It wasn't my fault the code is fine. The problem is that the python binding of SFML seems buggy when accessing the location function directly. I switched to the "move" function and everything's working now... Sorry for bothering you all.